# Passing reference type as parameter and using generics

Tags: java, generics

I am learning generics in java and came across this problem.

I have a Weather interface. `EarthQuake` and `VirginiaWeather` are two classes that implement the `Weather` interface. Both these classes have a static method - `"parseData"` which parse the data from atom feed. The `getFeeds` method in the Main class has a parameter `"String type"`, which I use to find out which class' method I should call.
Can anybody please help me to understand if generics can be used to make the code a bit cleaner. Can I pass the class type as an argument to the method and use that class type to call the `parseData` method in the appropriate class.
I tried to do 
`list.add(T.parseData((Element) nl.item(i)));`
but got:

> The method parseData(Element) is undefined for the type T

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<EarthQuake> quakes = getFeeds("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.atom", "quakes");
    List<VirginiaWeather> weather = getFeeds("http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/va.php?x=0", "weather");
    //Get Earthquake data
    System.out.println("Earthquake data");
    for (EarthQuake e: quakes)
        System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%f\t%s\n",(e.getDate()),e.getLocation(),e.getMagnitude(),e.getDetails());
    //Get Virginia weather data
    System.out.println("Virginia Weather");
    for (VirginiaWeather vw: weather)
        System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",vw.getUpdated(),vw.getTitle(),vw.getEvent(),vw.getEffective(),vw.getExpires());
}


private static <T> List<T> getFeeds(String url, String type) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        URL usgsUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = usgsUrl.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
        int response = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

        if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = db.parse(in);
            Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList nl = element.getElementsByTagName("entry");

            if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0)
                for(int i =0 ; i<nl.getLength() ; i++)
                {
                    if(type.equals("quakes"))
                    {
                        list.add((T) EarthQuake.parseData((Element) nl.item(i)));
                    }
                    if(type.equals("weather"))
                    {
                        list.add((T) VirginiaWeather.parseData((Element) nl.item(i)));
                    }
                }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

    }
    return list;
}

}
```

Comment: `type == "quakes"` euh that's not good

Comment: What RC means is that you should compare objects using `equals()` - and strings are objects.

Comment: Java Generics are kind of strange in that the type parameters aren't actually bound to the class, which is why you see things like JAXB take the java.lang.Class as well as the Generic type.  The pragmatic approach is to define an interface which will transform the text into an element; the esoteric is to use reflection to obtain the class method from the class and invoke it.

Comment: Thank you RC and Thomas. I have changed it to use .equals()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a typed factory.  First create an interface:

```
interface WeatherDataFactory<T> {
    T parse(Element element);
}
```

Then write your concrete weather data factories:

```
class VirginiaWeatherDataFactory implements WeatherDataFactory<VirginiaWeather> {
    @Override
    public VirginiaWeather parse(final Element element) { ... }
}
```

Then your `getFeeds` method will look like this:

```
private static <T> List<T> getFeeds(String url, WeatherDataFactory<T> factory) {
    ...
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        for(int i =0 ; i<nl.getLength() ; i++) {
            list.add(factory.parse(nl));
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, most implementations of `NodeList#item(int)` perform like a linked list, in that the whole list has to be traversed to get element *n*.  Your program will be extremely slow if the list is large.

Comment: Thank you, if using NodeList.item(i) will be slow can you please suggest an alternate method

Comment: @BKVP Google "DOM vs. SAX".  You're using DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the facilities of Java 8?

```
private static <T> List<T> getFeeds(String url, Function<Element, T> parser) { 
   // [..snip..]
   for(int i =0 ; i<nl.getLength() ; i++) {
        list.add(parser.call((Element) nl.item(i)));
   }
   // [..snip..]
 }
```

You use it like this:

```
List<EarthQuakes> eq = getFeeds("http://....", EarthQuake::parseData);
List<VirginiaWeather> eq = getFeeds("http://....", VirginiaWeather::parseData);
```

It might be more useful in the long term to have a factory class that manages parsing, instead of merging data representation and parsing in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use typed class.

```
 public interface Weather<T>(){
        private static <T> List<T> getFeeds(String url, String type);
}
```

And the other class

```
 public class EarthQuake implements Weather<EarthQuake> {

     }
```